# Ancient One Yig's reckoning Effect Spawning 1 cultist

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore

Part of Ancient One Yig's's setup is to set aside 6 cultist monsters. Yig's reckoning effect is Spawn 1 cultist monster on the active expedition space.

My question is what happened if I ran out of the set aside 6 cultist monsters? Meaning all of the 6 cultist monster is still on the board.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, they don't spawn. From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf), page 3, **Component Limitations** (which did take me a fair amount of digging to find the actual rule!)

> Monsters cannot be spawned from the Monster cup if the Monster
> cup is empty. **Set aside Monsters cannot be spawned if all set aside
> Monsters of the named type are on the game board.**